# Excel VBA - Trying to add multiple columns from multiple files in to one master file

Tags: excel, vba

fairly new to VBA so please bear with me.

I've seen a few approaches on this forum on what I want to do, but I'm struggling to get this working. So, the context:

I have a folder with multiple excel files (10s of them) that each have 2-3 worksheets in them. I specifically need columns A, D, F, and Q from a worksheet name that contains the word "Capture" (every file will have a worksheet with this word and an associated date so I figure selecting that word makes the most sense). From there I would like these columns added to a master spreadsheet. As I transfer the date from the 4 columns to this master spreadsheet I would like each subsequent file to add its 4 columns next to what's already transferred and not overwrite what's there. Effectively, over time, more excel files will be added to this folder so I would like to run this macro at a future date to update the master file, but at that point I can start a whole new master sheet to amalgamate everything. So here's what I got so far that's not working:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Wb As Workbook, _
    Ws As Worksheet, _
    PasteRow As Long

Filepath = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Measurements"
Set Ws = ActiveSheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "master.xlsm" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

For Each Ws In Worksheets
    If InStr(1, Ws.Name, "Capture", vbTextCompare) Then
        Ws.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next

    PasteRow = Ws.Range("A" & Ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)
    Wb.Sheets(1).Range("A,D,F,Q").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & PasteRow)
    Wb.Close

    MyFile = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any thoughts, corrections, or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much to those willing to help me.

Comment: Notably, you have defined `Ws` as ActiveSheet. You are applying a dynamic variable to a constant action.

Comment: I have removed the line of code and I'm still not seeing any functionality. Do I need to set Ws as something else?

Comment: You should define it so that the macro knows the constant location that you are referencing. Change it to something like `Set Ws = worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: No dice. You'll have to forgive my incompetence as I'm still trying to get better at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after speaking with @JoshPachner I now have a fully functioning VBA script that does exactly what I want it to do. A couple of alterations in my logic came up here as @JoshPachner was kind enough to point out my approach could be optimized. An example of this was when I said "As I transfer the date from the 4 columns to this master spreadsheet I would like each subsequent file to add its 4 columns next to what's already transferred and not overwrite what's there" and with this I was merely setting up my data to be manipulated at a later date with some visual separation. However, I did not consider how having that separation would ultimately make things more complicated. Why not just have the columns I requested and just add more rows? And that is the approach that was taken. Honestly, can't thank you enough @JoshPachner. For anyone else reading this, this man is a wonderful teacher, extremely knowledgeable, very patient, and just downright a great guy. Again, thank you! Now for the code:

```
Sub the_button()

Dim sFolder As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
     .Title = "Select a Folder"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    If sFolder <> "" Then

folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(folder)
Set FSOFile = FSOFolder.Files
Set mainWb = ActiveWorkbook

For Each file In FSOFile
    If file Like "*master*" Then
        GoTo nextFile
    End If
    
    Set newWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file)
    
    For Each ws In newWb.Sheets
        If Not ws.Name Like "*Capture*" Then
            GoTo nextWs
        End If
       
        lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        theDate = Trim(Split(ws.Name)(1))
        irow = 1
        Do Until IsEmpty(ws.Cells(irow, "A"))
            lotNum = ws.Cells(irow, "A")
            arr = ws.Cells(irow, "A").CurrentRegion
        
            mainWb.Activate
            
            lr = shData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            For j = 2 To UBound(arr)
                If arr(j, 2) = "" Then
                Else
                    shData.Cells(lr + j - 1, "A") = lotNum
                    shData.Cells(lr + j - 1, "B") = arr(j, 4)
                    shData.Cells(lr + j - 1, "C") = arr(j, 6)
                    shData.Cells(lr + j - 1, "D") = arr(j, 17)
                    shData.Cells(lr + j - 1, "E") = theDate
                End If
            Next j
            
            irow = ws.Cells(irow, "A").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
            
        Loop
        
nextWs:
    Next ws

    newWb.Close savechanges:=False
nextFile:

Next file
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:
Without the files its hard to test to make sure this has no bugs but this might help you...

```
 Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim Filepath As String
 Dim Wb, newWb As Workbook, _
  Ws, MainWS As Worksheet, _
  PasteRow As Long

 Filepath = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Measurements"
 set Wb as activeworkbook 
 Set MainWS = ActiveSheet ' you will be referencing this page for future drop off
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
 
 While Filename <> ""
   If MyFile = "master.xlsm" Then
       ' might not want to exit sub yet... since there could be files that come after this maybe just skip it?
       'goto nextFile
       Exit Sub
   else
      Set newWb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)       
   End If

 dim columnA, columnD, columnF, columnQ as variant ' to be used as arrays
 For Each Ws In Worksheets
   If InStr(1, Ws.Name, "Capture", vbTextCompare) Then
       lastRow = Ws.Range("A"&rows.count).end(xlUp).row ' assuming all your data has equal amount of rows
       columnA = Ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow) 'grab the data you want. Don't copy and paste. - its extremely slow.. better practice is to put the data into arrays.  
       columnD = Ws.Range("D1:D" & lastRow)
       columnF = Ws.Range("F1:F" & lastRow)
       columnQ = Ws.Range("Q1:Q" & lastRow)
       Wb.Activate 'need to activate main wb
       lastColumn = MainWS.cells(1,columns.count).end(xlToLeft).column 
       dim j as integer ' common to use j as counter to loop through arrays
       for j = 1 to ubound(columnA) 'ubound gives us how many "rows" are in columnA
            MainWs.cells(j,lastColumn +1) = columnA(j,1)
            MainWs.cells(j,lastColumn +2) = columnD(j,1)
            MainWs.cells(j,lastColumn +3) = columnF(j,1)
            MainWs.cells(j,lastColumn +4) = columnQ(j,1)
       next j
       newWb.Activate ' go back to newly open wb
   End If
Next Ws


 newWb.Close
'nextFile:
 MyFile = Dir

 Wend

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Let me know if this helps! i will add more if needed.

Basically Loop through Directory

Open Wb -- variable newWb

Loop Through its Worksheets

Grab the content from the right columns

drop them off to the main wb, main ws

close newWb

next Filename

Comment: Hey @JoshPachner, really appreciate the help on this. So far no luck yet. I did notice your comment about the `lastrow`and no my data does not all have the same amount of rows, unfortunately. The data saved in the various excel files are all the same format, but exist as blocks of 18 columns (A-R) and 6 rows each followed by an empty row between each block. Depending on what analysis was done in a given day these blocks can range from a few to tens in length. I'm assuming this will change the approach. I can certainly post some sample data files if you think it will help.

Comment: Doesn't change it that much. When you are outputting the data it will include that empty row, or if you want to have that row omited you can just have it say something like--- if columnA(j,1) = "" then...

Comment: @joshanky if the data samples are too sensitive to post we can always chat via email about it.

Comment: I will likely take you up on that offer as the data is a little more sensitive. If all works out in the end I can certainly post the solution we came to in the event it could help others in the future.